# XML parsing PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

script return error

```
v_xml := XMLTYPE(UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => 'http://www.nbg.ge/rss.php'));
```

[image]

the CDATA  length is 6227,  how I can extract data from this XML

Comment: Please try to build a [mcve] that can help people to understand and replicate your issue and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to replicate this problem:

```
declare
  v_xml xmltype;
begin
  v_xml := XMLTYPE(UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => 'http://www.nbg.ge/rss.php'));
end;
```

However there seems to be nothing wrong with the XML itself. If I put the URL in a browser and get the XML there. It will parse into an XMLTYPE.

```
declare
  v_xml xmltype ;
begin
  v_xml  :=  xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>RSS NBG Currency Rates</title>
      .... rest of the xml ....
   </channel>
</rss>
');
end;
```

Problem is probably with getting a long string from the request.
The following code will take care of it reading the data in chunks of 2000.

```
declare
   l_clob                  clob;
   l_req                   utl_http.req;
   l_resp                  utl_http.resp;
   l_buffer                varchar2(4096);
   l_pos                   pls_integer;
   l_xml   xmltype;

begin

   dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => l_clob, cache => true, dur => dbms_lob.call);

   -- -----------------------------------
   -- OPEN TEMPORARY LOB FOR READ / WRITE
   -- -----------------------------------
   dbms_lob.open(lob_loc => l_clob, open_mode => dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

   l_req := utl_http.begin_request('http://www.nbg.ge/rss.php');

   utl_http.set_header(l_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
   utl_http.set_header(l_req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
   l_resp := utl_http.get_response(l_req);

   begin
      loop
         utl_http.read_text(r => l_resp, data => l_buffer, len => 2000);

         dbms_lob.writeappend(lob_loc => l_clob, amount => length(l_buffer), buffer => l_buffer);

      end loop;
   exception
      when utl_http.end_of_body then
         null;
      when others then
         raise;
   end;

   utl_http.end_response(l_resp);

   l_xml := xmltype(l_clob);

end;
```